# MongoDB not logging to log file

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB on OSX, with mongod confirmed running. I checked the mongod.conf file and the following is present and unmodified:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
```

So far so good. The path location exists, however the folder is empty - no mongo.log. This was a standard installation and everything has been fine so far except this. Any idea on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Check permissions? Does the user that is starting the `mongod` process have full privileges on that log directory? Ability to create new files? Are you sure that this is the config file being loaded/

Comment: I chmod 777 the mongodb folder, and used 'mongod -f' to load the config file. Now my log/mongodb is filled with Wiredtiger files, journal and diagnostic.data folder amongst other files but no mongo.log?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Context**

I deleted my mongod.log file once.  Then I recreated it and ran into this exact problem.  I may have deleted the /var/log/mongodb folder as well, then recreated it.

I was reading under **Run Mongodb Community Edition**:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

> The MongoDB instance stores its data files in /var/lib/mongodb and its log files in /var/log/mongodb by default, and runs using the mongodb user account.

I read into this way too much and assumed the user who starts the mongodb service is the "mongodb user account". This is incorrect.  They literally mean the user: **mongodb**

### **Solution**

```
sudo chown mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```